# file in python formatting

Tags: python, dictionary

So here is a file

```
APPLE: toronto, 2018, garden, tasty, 5
apple is a tasty fruit
>>>end 
Orange: japan, 32, home, sour, 1
orange is a sour fruit
>>>end
graEes: america, 24, organic, sweet, 4
grapes is a sweet fruit
>>>end
```

This is a file which also has new line characters. 
I want tp create a dictionary using the file. it goes like this

the function is def f(file_to: (TextIO))-> Dict[str, List[tuple]]

file_to is file name entered and it will return the dictionary like,

```
{'apple': ['apple is a tasty fruit', 2018, 'garden', 'tasty', 5], orange:['orange is a sour fruit', 32,'home', 'sour',1] then grapes......}
```

each of the fruit is key and their discription is values as formatted there. Each fruits ends at >>>end

I tried

```
with open (file_to, "r") as myfile:
    data= myfile.readlines()
return data
```

it returns the file strings in a list with /n I'm thinking I can use strip() to remove that and get the element that comes before ':' as keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this simple example, the following gives the results you want. (Although you probably misspelled grapes).

```
from pprint import pprint
import re

def main():
    fin = open('f1.txt', 'r')

    data = {}
    key = ''
    parsed = []
    for line in fin:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith('>'):
            data[key] = parsed
            parsed = []
        elif ':' in line:
            parts = re.split('\W+', line)
            key = parts[0].lower()
            parsed += parts[2:]
        else:
            parsed.insert(0, line)

    fin.close()
    pprint(data)


main()
```